# git push error , because it has a working copy

Tags: git

I pushed my code to the remote end as usual, but the push failed, prompting "[remote rejected] (Gitblit does not allow pushes to XXXX" because it has a working copy! " ,what shouid i do,Please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCCrW.png)

Comment: i think it is related to `gitblit`, not git itself.

Comment: Is `gitblit` a hosting service set up by yourself? For a server side repository, it's required to be initialized as a bare repository. The error indicates it's been initialized as a normal repository that has a work tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+working+tree

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+refusing+to+update+checked+out+branch